# What is the maximum possible time zone difference

Tags: timezone

What is the maximum possible difference between two time zones?

First thought is 24 hours, but with Daylight Saving, is it 26?

Comment: Almost all programs have to deal with time and dates at some point. I just found myself asking this very question when writing/testing a scheduler. It seems 22 people/day agree with me. It's answerable and it might help people writing/testing timezone related code (which is always a nightmare).

Comment: as thoroughly explained in [Quora](http://qr.ae/ROZvjE), for those who happen to fall here instead of there, it's impossible to have 26h+ - but not because of DST.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The maximum difference is at least 26 hours, as there are time zones for GMT-12 all the way to GMT+14. With DST, that may go up to 27 hours.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone : Looks like -12 and +14 don't observe any sort of time shift (DST), but +12:45 does shift to +13:45.

Comment: This is a handy link for seeing the current DST-adjusted time in most parts of the world http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/custom.html?continent=all&sort=2&low=0 Currently shows a 26 hour gap.

Comment: If your program accepts and represents historical data, then the maximum difference could be over 30 hours. See http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/10520.1338415812@sss.pgh.pa.us

Comment: as thoroughly explained in [Quora](http://qr.ae/ROZvjE), for those who happen to fall here instead of there, it's impossible to have 26h+, as @JamieF said.