# Allow read in FireStore rules based on timestamp value in document

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a FireStore rule that grantes read privilages to documents after the current date has surpassed a timestamp value in the document.

This is for a blog web application. 
E.G a blogger sets a blog post to be available to the public on a certain date.

From reading the documentation this should work, but It dosn't.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Articles/{article}{
   allow read: if request.time.date() < resource.data.date
    }
  }
}
```

What I am i missing ??

Comment: how you saving your date?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*firebaser here*

I tried the same thing a while ago, and found out it isn't currently possible.

It *is* possible to allow/deny read to a specific document based on a property of that document.

It *is* possible to allow a query that filters documents based on a property in that document, but currently that is only possible based on `request.auth`.

This means that unfortunately your filter currently can't be implemented with security rules. I recommend you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to chime in.

**Update** (2018-04-24): this *might* now be possible with `request.time`, but I haven't had a chance to test yet. Have a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#properties).

Comment: Thanks for the response Frank. I will file a feature request 

Comment: any luck with date based rules?

Comment: I tested the approach mentioned in the Update ant it worked. Comparing with `request.time` is possible.

Answer (score 7):

**NOTE:** As this is my first answer on Stack Overflow, I wasn't allowed to comment on [Frank van Pueffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen)'s answer, so just as a heads-up, the credits for this solution are his!

The request has a `request.time` which is a timestamp, and Firestore allows for basic math operators on `timestamp <> timestamp` operations, so your `request.time < resource.data.date` will work ;)

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Articles/{article}{
   allow read: if request.time < resource.data.date
    }
  }
}
```

*This is based on my personal testing on 2018.09.29*

Answer (score 6):

trying switching the < to >.

request.time will be the time of accessing the document while resource.data.date should be the creation timestamp of the document.

try using this for your security rules:

```
    allow read: if request.time > (resource.data.timestampPropertyName + duration.time(1, 0, 0, 0));
```

duration.time(4, 3, 2, 1) will create a four hour, three minute, two second, one nanosecond duration.

More information can be found at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#timestamp

Do remember to wait for sometime after saving your security rules for it to take effect!

Comment: Where in the docs does it mention that `duration` is a global object, and that `time` is a method? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Answer of @user776914 is nice but what if there are diff timezones

Lets add +- 27 hours to be sure it was e.g. created in that day +- 1

```
duration.abs(request.time - request.resource.data.created) < duration.value(27, 'h')
```

[What's max timezone offset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8131056/5279156)

Comment: According to the document https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp timestamp is independent from timezones.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do a similar thing for a game. I wanted to activate and deactivate a game object only after a particular date. I used google's cloud functions to do it. I deployed a function that runs every day to check the firestore documents and changes values according to the script.