# Firestore where query does not work

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

We have used [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md) and following query gave permission error:

```
af.collection<any>(`tours`, ref =>
  ref.where('startDate', '<', new Date()).where('front_page', '==', true))
```

But the same query works fine with [firebase-admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore) in cloud functions:

```
admin.firestore().collection('tours').where('startDate', '<', new Date()).where('front_page', '==', true).get()
```

Here is firestore rules:

```
match /tours/{tourId}{
 allow read:  if (resource.data.startDate.date() < request.time.date());
 allow write: if isAdmin();
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't (currently) possible to validate the query based on `request.time`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414073/allow-read-in-firestore-rules-based-on-timestamp-value-in-document

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ah, then it seems to be an issue with firebase client js for time-based queries? As the same query works well with firebase-admin.

Comment: If you initialize it with a credentials JSON, the admin SDK is bypassing your rules. As far as I understand, the server-side security rules simply don't support checking `request.time` when using a query.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Actually, server-side rules seems to work fine if we try to read single record with angualrfier2 if they pass the security rule, otherwise show permission error,  this.af.doc<any>(`tours/${tourId}`)