# android studio firebase firestore : Permission_denied

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is my first time using firebase with android studio and specifically firebase firestore . I have a form where I submit my data and try to insert it in my firestore db . When I fill the form and submit I get this message from `W/Firestore` in my console :

[image]

Which just denies permission to my firestore db . No error hits in my app as if nothing happened and my document is not inserted in the firestore db .

My code to insert doc :

```
  mFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("name", name.getText().toString());
        data.put("surname", surname.getText().toString());
        data.put("email", email.getText().toString());
        data.put("amka", amka.getText().toString());
        data.put("phone", phone.getText().toString());

        mFireStore.collection("people").add(data).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                Toast.makeText(root.getContext(),"User added" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull @NotNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(root.getContext(),e.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

My build.gradle on project level :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My build.gradle module in the app level

```
apply plugin:'com.android.application'
apply plugin:'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.covid19gate"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.5.1'
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.1")
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

And lastly the rules in my firestore db :

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 7, 8);
    }
  }
}
```

I would appreciate your help .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414073/allow-read-in-firestore-rules-based-on-timestamp-value-in-document